# Can we enable both catalog mode and checkout together?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to use the catalog mode, where a user can inquire about a product and for few of the products, there has to be added to cart and checkout option available. 
Is there any option available in Magento 2.1?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Default, there is no such functionality that we can set For some products inquiry Option and for some products Buy Now option.

But you can install the community Product inquiry Extension and using some minor customization on Product Page using One Custom boolean Product Attribute, you can enable inquiry or buy now option.